# What is the name of this style of design/illustration where cartoony items are surounded by a black/colored stroke?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have been seeing this style all over the internet and I would like to know its name, here's an example:

[image]

Comment: I don't know why they downvoted your question, anyway it's true they don't have a specific style name but they are usually referred to by "Colored Outline Icons"

Comment: @kapreski Thank you! yeah I noticed that the main feature was that the outline is colored, so I thought there might be a name for this style especially it's very characteristic and easily identifiable when you see it. 
I will be editing the question to add a new picture that better illustrates the concept.

Answer (score 1):

Art is not so definitive as to provide a specific name for everything you may see.

**Not every style of art has a name.**

I'd merely call this an "illustration"... *maybe* a "vector illustration". But that's making an assumption that it's vector in nature.

Beyond that, any words I would use to describe it - comic, cartoon, high contrast, etc. - would probably similar to what you use to describe it.